# Conditional formatting on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to format A1 when

- B1 is empty and A1 is lower than today

A1 is a date, like a deadline that I will print red if the deadline is not reached. B1 is the cell used to say it was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to conditional formatting and use the custom formula `=and(A1<today(),B1="")`
You can set the background color red there too.

EDIT: to extend the formatting down the column but not beyond where you have date, you can do apply to range A:A and amend the formula to `=and(isDate(A1),A1<today(),B1="")`

Here is a picture [image: screen shot]

Comment: It wont let me add the "=" before the formula, it gives me an error saying the formula is incorrect. Do you know how to fix it? I wont let me enter the "=" when using the AND operator

Comment: Not so helpful perhaps, but it worked for me. Did you select Custom formula is? You are using Google sheets, right? Anyway, here is a link to mine, for now, and you may copy it to play with. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fAKDopeKNkPWSYcegehMJ0tEw9bjkqOu8o65KrT5lJ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: well, I had to change my sheets' locale to United States. Weired, but now it works. Thanks

Comment: For how to enter it, see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en  at the section Use advanced conditional formatting
under Use custom formulas with conditional formatting and see their example 1. Here I'm using =and() as a function. For what it is worth, I am using firefox, but that should not matter.

Comment: I think this might relate to the date and locale issue: https://onlinejournalismblog.com/2016/07/19/how-to-fix-spreadsheet-dates-that-are-in-both-us-and-uk-formats/ Anyway, I'm glad it is working for you now.